# How to install win xp beside win 7?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dual boot when Windows XP was installed after Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/305764/how-to-dual-boot-when-windows-xp-was-installed-after-windows-7)

Now,I have win 7 and I am running win xp on the virtual machine but it is too slow.So, I want to know if there is a way to install windows XP in parallel with win 7.

Comment: This is not a programming question (it's an operating system installation question), and therefore it's off-topic here at StackOverflow. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has information about what types of questions should be asked here. Voting to close and move your question to a more appropriate site. Please try and keep your questions on-topic; it keeps noise and clutter down and helps SO stay a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Comment: instructions at the bottom of my post here...http://superuser.com/questions/270065/dual-booting-xp-with-windows-7-with-windows-7-already-installed

Answer (score 1):

Use some other HDD or some other drive in the same HDD.
But remember, when installing in the same HDD always take a backup of the hidden file "ntldr". It is hidden somewhere in C: or your WinXP drive, and is easily searchable.

The benefit of doing so would be that while installing Windows 7, sometimes, the file gets deleted automatically, preventing you from booting Windows XP ever again. By taking a backup of the file and noting down the location of the file, it can be easily pasted back to its original location if it gets deleted so that you're able to boot for Windows XP as well as Windows 7 from the same HDD.

If you choose to install both the OSs in different HDDs, however, then you need not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use another partition on the HDD or a second HDD and then have a dual boot setting in boot.ini

Comment: or he can use grub.